# How i can get attribute sort by

Tags: sorting

If i change the sort order for cagegory - the page is reloaded and displayed in the address bar: ?dir=asc&order=name and order sorting attribute - How i can get the attributes order=name?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('order'); //should return 'name'
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('dir'); //should return 'asc'
```